# How to align the top lines of frames?

Tags: showexpl

I want to align the top lines of the left and right frames. How to do it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm,showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand*{\noaccsupp}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}

\usepackage{showexpl}

\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    alsolanguage={PSTricks},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=1em,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{red}\noaccsupp,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\small\tt,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    %identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.54,0.13},
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
    explpreset={pos=r},
    morekeywords={
        graphicspath,
        includegraphics,
    },
}




\begin{document}
\LTXexample
How to align the top lines of frames?\\
How to align the top lines of frames?
\endLTXexample
How to align the top lines of frames?
\LTXexample
How to align the top lines of frames?\\
How to align the top lines of frames?
\endLTXexample
\end{document}
```

Note: `accsupp` only works when this input file is compiled with either `xelatex` or `pdflatex`. Compiling it with `latex` followed by `dvips` and `ps2pdf` will not produce a PDF output that allows us not to copy the line numbers.

Comment: I think rather than messing with `showexpl` I would just use `listings`, a `tabular` environment, `minipage`s and then you should be able to put the stuff in `\savebox`es to measure the heights and put them where they belong. No easy way to do such a simple thing as vertical alignment in LaTeX, it's quite sad. I'm sorry I don't have the time for a proper answer right now :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain where the problem is located, and a possible workaround. Be warned, the workaround is very ugly!

The problem is located at different places in the code of `showexpl` and `listings` packages (`listings` is used by `showexpl`).

The way the package works is the following: it outputs the code into a intermediate file, then it uses `listings` package to input the code and typeset it nicely formatted, with listings options (in your case, with a red frame around). Finally it stores the result of "executing" that code through TeX into a temporal box, and outputs that box too, side to side with the one created by `listings`.

The problem is thus how to align the box created by `listings` (framed in red) and the one created by latex (framed in black in your example).

The package `showexpl` uses parbox to create both boxes, so apparently it would be enough to insert [t] at the appropiate places, to have "top aligned" parboxes. So the first guess is to add the following in your preamble (after including `showexpl` package):

```
\makeatletter
 \renewcommand\SX@CodeArea[2]{%
   \parbox[t]{#1}{#2}
   \rlap{\parbox[t]{#1}{\SX@attachfile}}}
\renewcommand\SX@ResultArea[2]{%
  \SX@justification%
  \parbox[t]{#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother
```

However, this alone won't work. Now the two parboxes are "top" aligned, but "top" alignment only means "move the baseline of the parbox to the baseline of the first line of the parbox".

[image: Not working example]

The problem is that the left box (red frame) and the right box (black frame) have a different concept of what the "first line" is. We have to insert an empty first line ("null box" or `\hbox{}`) at the beginning of both parboxes, so that they align properly.

In order to insert a `\hbox{}` at the beginning of the left box, we have to make `listings` to insert that command before it renders the listing. This can be done using `listings` `basicstyle` option: `basicstyle=\small\tt\hbox{},` (yucks!)

In order to insert a `\hbox{}` at the beginning of the right box, we have to modify the code in `showexpl` which builds that box (called `\SX@ResBox`). Unfortunately that code is deeply buried inside a macro definition (`\SX@put@code@result`), so we have to rewrite the complete macro (63 lines of code!) in order to change only two lines inside it.

So the final, complete, code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=25mm,showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand*{\noaccsupp}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}

\usepackage{showexpl}
\makeatletter

% Add [t] to the parbox
\renewcommand\SX@CodeArea[2]{%
   \parbox[t]{#1}{#2}
   \rlap{\parbox[t]{#1}{\SX@attachfile}}}

% Add [t] to the parbox
\renewcommand\SX@ResultArea[2]{%
  \SX@justification%
  \parbox[t]{#1}{#2}%
}

% Add \hbox{} at the creation of \SX@ResBox, look up the comment
\renewcommand*\SX@put@code@result{%
  \begingroup
    \expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\SX@explpreset}%
    \let\lst@float=\relax\let\SX@float=\relax
    \expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\SX@@explpreset}%
    \ifx\lst@float\relax\else
      \let\SX@float=\lst@float\let\lst@float=\relax
      \g@addto@macro\SX@@explpreset{,float=false}%
      \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\lst@beginfloat{lstlisting}[\SX@float]}%
      \expandafter\@tempa
    \fi
    \ifx\lst@caption\@empty
      \lstset{nolol=true}%
    \fi
    \if@SX@wide\def\SX@overhang{\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}\fi
    \trivlist\item\relax
      \stepcounter{ltxexample}\label{\SX@IDENT}%
      \SX@defaultWD\SX@width{\SX@width}%
      \ifdim\SX@width<\z@
        \@tempswatrue
        \def\@tempa{t}%
        \ifx\@tempa\SX@pos\@tempswafalse\fi
        \def\@tempa{b}%
        \ifx\@tempa\SX@pos\@tempswafalse\fi
        \setlength\@tempdima{\linewidth+\SX@overhang}%
        \if@tempswa\@tempdima=.5\@tempdima\fi%
        \edef\SX@width{\the\@tempdima}%
      \fi
      \ifx\SX@rframe\@empty
        \long\def\SX@frame##1{##1}%
      \else
        \let\SX@frame\fbox
        \setlength\@tempdima{\SX@width-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
        \edef\SX@width{\the\@tempdima}%
      \fi
      \isSX@odd{\def\@tempa{l}}{\def\@tempa{r}}%
      \makebox[\linewidth][\@tempa]{%
        \parbox{\linewidth+\SX@overhang}{%
          \let\@addtofilelist\@gobble
          \let\lst@ifdisplaystyle=\iftrue
          \SX@KillAboveCaptionskip\lst@MakeCaption{t}%
          \lst@belowskip=\z@
          \let\SX@MakeCaption\lst@MakeCaption
          \let\lst@MakeCaption\@gobble
          \setbox\SX@ResBox\vtop{\hbox{}\hbox{%    <---- HERE, modified line
            \SX@frame{%
              \@nameuse{\if@SX@varwidth varwidth\else minipage\fi}%
                \SX@width\relax\SX@resultInput%
                \@nameuse{end\if@SX@varwidth varwidth\else minipage\fi}}}}% <-- Also here, to close a brace
          \edef\SX@width{\the\wd\SX@ResBox}%
          \@ifundefined{SX@put@\SX@pos}%
            {\@latex@error{Parameter `\SX@pos' undefined}\@ehd}%
          {\@nameuse{SX@put@\SX@pos}%
            {\SX@width}{\box\SX@ResBox}{\SX@codeInput}}%
          \let\lst@MakeCaption\SX@MakeCaption
          \lst@MakeCaption{b}\SX@KillBelowCaptionskip
        }%
      }%
    \endtrivlist
    \ifx\SX@float\relax\else\expandafter\lst@endfloat\fi
    \gdef\SX@@explpreset{}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    alsolanguage={PSTricks},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=1em,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{red}\noaccsupp,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\small\tt\hbox{},  % <--- Add \hbox{} here too
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    %identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.54,0.13},
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
    explpreset={pos=r},
    morekeywords={
        graphicspath,
        includegraphics,
    },
}


\begin{document}
\LTXexample
How to align the top lines of frames?\\
How to align the top lines of frames?
\endLTXexample
How to align the top lines of frames?
\LTXexample
How to align the top lines of frames?\\
How to align the top lines of frames?
\endLTXexample
\end{document}
```

Which works as desired

[image: Working result]

Answer (score 5):

A "simple" workaround using TikZ:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand*{\noaccsupp}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\SX@put@r[3]{%
  \setlength\@tempdimc{\linewidth-#1-\SX@hsep}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(expl.north)}]
    \node[draw=red,anchor=base west,line width=1pt,inner sep=1pt,fill=yellow!10]
    (expl){\SX@CodeArea{\@tempdimc}{#3}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \hfill%
  \tikz[baseline={(expl.north)}]\node[inner sep=0pt]%
  (expl){\SX@ResultArea{#1}{#2}};
}
\makeatother

\lstset
{
      language={[LaTeX]TeX},
      alsolanguage={PSTricks},
      numbers=left,
      numbersep=1em,
      numberstyle=\tiny\color{red}\noaccsupp,
      rulecolor=\color{red},
      breaklines=true,
      basicstyle=\small\tt,
      keywordstyle=\color{blue},
      %identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
      commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.54,0.13},
      tabsize=2,
      columns=flexible,
      explpreset={pos=r},
      morekeywords={
          graphicspath,
          includegraphics,
      },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}
How to align the top lines of frames?\\
How to align the top lines of frames?
\end{LTXexample}
How to align the top lines of frames?
\begin{LTXexample}
How to align the top lines of frames?\\
How to align the top lines of frames?
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @PeterGrill The overfull \hbox is coming from my `inner sep` value (5pt instead of 1pt)... Look at my new version.

Comment: `\begin{LTXexample}\lipsum\end{LTXexample}` will produce a truncated formatted output.

Comment: @Forgiver Have you try this without my patch ? It's another problem. So, it's another question...

Comment: @PolGab: yes of course. It is another problem that must be asked in a new question. But please wait for other solutions (if any).

Comment: @Forgiver I think that is a limitation of `showexpl` package. It was designed to show "little" example... like all other similar packages.

Answer (score 4):

define after loading package `showexpl`

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\SX@CodeArea[2]{%
  \setlength\@tempdima{#1}%
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\parbox\@tempdima{#2}}%
  \@tempdima=\dp\@tempboxa\raisebox{\dimexpr -\baselineskip-\fboxsep-\fboxrule-2pt}{\usebox\@tempboxa}
  \rlap{\raisebox{-\@tempdima}[0pt][0pt]{\SX@attachfile}}}
\makeatother
```

2pt is the interlineskip

[image]

Comment: If you see the output carefully (at more than 100% magnification), the top of frames are not exactly aligned.

Comment: @Forgiver: maybe, but when I run your example I have only a frame on the left side, the code part.

Comment: If you compile my code (without your code snippet), it should look like the attached screen shot above.

Comment: no, i get the right code without a frame ( current texlive 2011)

Comment: I also used TeX Live 2011 but I got both frames.

Comment: But in your source code is no `\fbox` or the like. So the question is which command draws the right frames?

Comment: If I add `rframe={}` to `\lstset{}` then the right frame disappears.

Comment: uh ... your example code has no `rframe=single` ... However, see my edited answer ...

Comment: @Herbert Code and documentation of showexpl package are not "aligned": by default `rframe=single`.

Comment: `rframe=single` by default, that is why I don't need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: Your answer is almost perfect as the top line of the left frame is a bit lower than that of the right frame. I think the length expression must be corrected, but how? I don't know.

Comment: try `1.5pt` instead of `2pt`